# How to graphically represent and manipulate apache avro schema

Tags: apache, schema, visualization, avro

I have been working with apache avro lately, where i was writing the avro schema files by myself, now i am dealing with other developers schema and looking for a tool to visualize the schema to save me sometime, and it would be better if this tool also capable of manipulating the schema. My question is there are any tools that server my need?

Comment: Instead of writing the schema in IDL or JSON manually you can try to use the SchemaBuilder: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/SchemaBuilder.html - for simple visualization I'd recommend dumping the Schema as JSON and pretty printing it either in JAVA or with json_pp or jq.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment, so leaving this as an answer: This isn't a visualization tool, but if you're dealing with multiple schemata, I highly recommend writing protocol files ([Avro IDL](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/idl.html#defining_protocol)) instead of writing schemata directly. They're much easier to read, and each protocol file can compile down to multiple schema files.

As it can tersely define multiple schema files, it might make it easier to grok dependencies without needing a viewer.